# Read XML with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, xml

Here’s what I am trying to do. There is an XML file in the “forms” folder of each our SharePoint libraries called “client_LocationBasedDefaults.html” The file contains the column defaults that can be set in Library settings. The the XML looks like this

```
<MetadataDefaults>
  <a href="/RestoreTest/App">
    <DefaultValue FieldName="FunctionalClass">OPERATIONS</DefaultValue>
    <DefaultValue FieldName="BusinessUnit">Applications</DefaultValue>
  </a>
  <a href="/RestoreTest/App/Advance_Retail">
    <DefaultValue FieldName="FileNumber">REST10001-000002</DefaultValue>  
    <DefaultValue FieldName="FileLocationName">Restore Test==Restore Apps==Advance Retail</DefaultValue>
    <DefaultValue FieldName="ITSystem">Point of Sale</DefaultValue>
  </a>
</MetadataDefaults>
```

Here is a snippet of PowerShell which I have been experimenting with for a couple of days. I am able to pull out the href information no problem as well as the fieldnames but not the actual defaultvalues for example 'Point of Sale' . I think my knowledge of XML is probably wanting here. Anyway if someone could point me in the right direction I would be really grateful as I have pretty much exhausted my own limited knowledge and examples I have seen on the net don’t seem applicable.

```
$default = $document.OpenBinary()
$encode = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
[xml]$defaultXML = ($encode.GetString($default))
$content = $defaultXML.metadatadefaults
foreach($w in $content.a)
{
  if($w.href){
    Write-Host $w.href
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the XML-file and explain which default value you want to read from PowerShell? From the looks of it, you only need to append the XML-tag in `$content.[xml-tag]` and took for the XML-attribute in you if-statement. But the value can also be stored as a tag-value and not an attribute. So please edit your question, and add the XML-string you want to read from PowerShell.

Comment: Ooops how could I forget the XML. I can't figure out how to make it readable on the page.

Comment: Gotta use the `{}` button when you got your code selected. It just adds 4 spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: `jref`? Is that right?

Comment: Good pickup james.  Fixed it.

Comment: Strange that a topic related to a SharePoint XML which is central to its column defaulting functionality is off topic. I would imagine that being able to read that XML within the content of SharePoint would be useful to others especially those like myself trying to figure out why defaults in the XML are not corresponding with defaults actually applied to documents. Essentially that is the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: @tonym apparently it belongs on Stack Overflow. Kind of a winning situation for you, as SO gets a lot more traffic... #makingthebestofagrayarea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all values of all DefaultValue tags, you can do something like this:

```
foreach($w in $content.DefaultValue)
{
  Write-Host $w.InnerXML
}
```

Saving the array to a file, do this:

```
$output = @()

foreach($w in $content.DefaultValue)
{
  Write-Host $w.InnerXML
  $output += $w.InnerXML
}

$output > c:\temp\file.txt
```

and you will have a value on each row in the text file.

Reference: [Getting XML values in PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tswift/archive/2009/08/25/getting-xml-values-in-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Yes that does list all values but I was hoping there would be easy way of capturing the values for each href in some kind of report. Something like this:

Comment: @tonym To a text file or to a html page?

Comment: $XMLContent = [XML](Get-Content -path "D:\SharePoint_2010\DefaultXML.xml")

$XMLContent.SelectNodes('MetadataDefaults/a')

href DefaultValue

---- ------------

/RestoreTest/App {DefaultValue, DefaultValue}

/RestoreTest/App/Advance_Retail {DefaultValue, DefaultValue, Default...

But with the default values for each field showing. This would have been perfect if it actually displayed the values along with the corresponding fieldname.

Comment: Text file would be good.

Comment: @tonym I've edited my answer to include writing an array to a text file.

Comment: Thanks Benny. Not exactly what I was after but it has application for another task I'll be working on

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend querying based on XPath. The following should get you what you want:

```
[XML]$XMLContent = Get-Content -path "D:\SharePoint_2010\DefaultXML.xml"
$XMLContent.SelectNodes('//a//DefaultValue[@FieldName]')
```

A breakdown of the XPath: Any 'a' (//a) node that has a 'DefaultValue' (//DefaultValue) child node which has an attribute of 'FieldName' ([@FieldName]).

That statement outputs:

```
FieldName                             #text
---------                             -----
FunctionalClass                       OPERATIONS
BusinessUnit                          Applications
FileNumber                            REST10001-000002
FileLocationName                      Restore Test==Restore Apps==Advance Retail
ITSystem                              Point of Sale
```

A couple of points to note when working with XML. Your XPath queries ARE case-sensitive. I've burned time in the past having a query fail because it was 'name' instead of 'Name'. Always double check if you think it should be working. Second, the text such as 'Point of Sale' can be accessed by .'#text'. The quotes are necessary otherwise PowerShell will throw an error. Here is an example use:

```
$content.SelectNodes('//a//DefaultValue[@FieldName]') | `
  %{ Write-Host ("Field: {0}`t`tDefaultValue:  {1}" -f $_.FieldName,$_.'#text')}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was after except I want to work href into the equation as a report without it would be meaningless. I can see where I had been going wrong. I had been putting single slashes into the selectnodes. I would have stumbled on this had I got the syntax right. Is there some way I can add href into the report?

Comment: Something like this should get the job done: `$content.SelectNodes('//a[@href]') | %{Write-Host $_.href; $_.DefaultValue | %{Write-Host ("Field: {0}   DefaultValue: {1}" -f $_.FieldName,$_.'#text')}}` You'll have to tweak to get the output just right.